# How should I use the word 'signal' here?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use the word 'signal' in the following sentence? If not, how am I supposed to phrase it? I have no ideas.

**She told us she did notice that he tried in many times and in many ways to send her *signal*s that he secretly liked her.**

Comment: Looks good to me... you could probably omit the **in** before **many times**.

Comment: What @Catija said. In fact you *mustn't* include that first **in**, since it's grammatically invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the *in* before *many times*, then your sentence is fine. What you have written uses *signal* in a common and standard way.

> She told us she did notice that he tried many times and in many ways to send her signals that he secretly liked her.

However, you might also consider using *signal* as a verb. Doing so does not change the meaning of your sentence, but does affect the way it feels.

> She told us she did notice that he tried many times and in many ways to signal that he secretly liked her.

I think this reads a bit better. *In many ways* fits better here with *signal* than *send* to my eye, and this version sounds a little more active.

Answer (score -2):

**She had noticed his liking for her by various indications.**

Simple and right to the point. Using 'signal' here, may reduce the sophistication of what you are trying to convey.

Comment: I disagree that your version is simple; its diction is unnecessarily complex. It also changes the meaning. No longer is he actively and intentionally trying to convey his affections. Instead, she noticed for reasons unknown.

Comment: She told us she did notice that he **tried** in many times and in many ways to send her signals that he secretly **liked** her. 
It happened sometime in the past. If my answer fulfills the purpose, then it is as good an answer, irrespective of the simplicity.

Comment: My remark has nothing to do with the tense. "He tried ... to send her signals" tells us that he did something, but "she had noticed his liking for her by various indications" doesn't. With the latter, we have no idea what those indications are, but the former specifies them (they are the signals). Your suggestion changes the meaning, hence the downvote.

Comment: How can she notice indications unless something happened in the first place? It is implicit that she made the statement because of such occurrences. **No longer is he actively and intentionally trying to convey his affections.** states that we are discussing about some current action, which is contradictory in this scenario. Down vote was unasked for, since my answer, answers the question. She had noticed his interest in her through his various actions.